# run $(element).pulsate() under .live()

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically created elements on my page.
I want these elements to be pulstated using the  `$(element).pulsate()`

The thing is it doesn't work because they we created after running the page load.
I've notices there is a jquery `.live()` command.
How do I run the `pulsate()` under the live command?

Comment: `.live` is (was) for delegating events, not running arbitrary methods on elements.

Comment: When you create the elements, run the plugin on them. You don't need any additional method to do it. Don't over-think it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make it pulsate based on the click event, you can use `.on()`:

```
$(container).on('click', selector, function() {
    $(this).pulsate(...);
});
```

*The use of `.live()` has been deprecated since 1.7*

Where `container` is an element up in the DOM tree that's not removed while your app is running and `selector` is the relative query (anchored to the container) that's used to match elements you wish to pulsate when clicked.

**Example**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Some code would append a new element.

```
$('#container').append('<div class="bla">bla</div>');
```

Then this code could be used to achieve what you want:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.bla', function() {
    $(this).pulsate(...);
});
```

Comment: In sake of completeness for others reading this `on` is the successor to the jQuery `live` method. `live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is it doesn't work because they we created after running the page load.

So use `$(element).pulsate();` with an appropriate selector or element instances after you've created the elements. You haven't said how/when you're creating them, so I don't know whether it's on an event or a timer or what, but either way eventually you have code running that creates the elements. So tell them to pulsate as part of that code. E.g.:

```
/* ...add a bunch of content to #foo... */
$("#foo").pulsate();
```

You might use a class when creating the new elements (`class="new"`) so you can just blindly do this:

```
$(".new").pulsate().removeClass("new");
```